# htaccess is not returning right value

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm getting crazy using mod_rewrite.

My htaccess file looks like:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)/$ index.php?lang=$1&page=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ index.php?lang=$1
```

The `var_dump($_GET)` on `domain/en/Home/` shows

```
array(2)
{ 
          ["lang"]=> string(19) "redirect:/index.php" 
          ["page"]=> string(4) "Home" 
}
```

I don't know where the `redirect:/index.php` is coming from, but I discovered if I create a folder called `en` it works perfectly returning

```
array(2) 
{ 
        ["lang"]=> string(2) "en" 
        ["page"]=> string(4) "Home"
}
```

Can anybody explain to me this behaviour and how to solve it without creating useless empty folders?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Change your .htaccess to this

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)$ index.php?lang=$1&page=$2 [QSA]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?lang=$1 [QSA]
```

or you can make it easier and send only one varible to your index.php like this

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?data=$1 [QSA]
```

and in your index.php your index.php you need to do this

```
if(isset($_GET['data']))
{
   $data = explode("/",$_GET['data']);
   $lang = $data[0];
   if(isset($data[1]))
      $page = $data[1];
}
```

The second solution I gave you works in every case, however the first one sometimes doesn't work when you try to access to `domain/en/home/abcd`, in this case $_GET returns this

```
$_GET['lang'] = 'en/home';
$_GET['page']= 'abcd';
```

Comment: It still doesn't work, the $lang is used to read a file called $lang.txt and if the file doesn't exists it works, but when it's created instead of reciving en I'm reciving en.txt in the $_GET.

I can make it work if instead of **en.txt** the file is called **en**

Comment: did you try both solutions I posted ?

Comment: I tried de only one variable, but as I said for some reason is using the name of the file and not the content of the var, who knows how or why.

Comment: It's normal, you should remove the file

Comment: But the file is necessary because it keeps the translations. Why if I'm writing /en/Home/ I'm reciving en.txt/Home? That's what bothers me

Comment: try to close the browser, reopen or delete the cash .. may be it was kept in the cash

Comment: Doesn't work, I'll wait if somebody has an explanation, meanwhile I'll use your way to get all data in a var and explode it and changing the name of the file from en.txt to en. It's a dirty solution but it works. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

That is happening because your rewrite rules are looping more than once. Have your rules like this:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine on

# If the request is not for a valid directory
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [OR]
# If the request is not for a valid file
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ index.php?lang=$1&page=$2 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ index.php?lang=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Better to use `[^/]+` instead of `.*` here.

Comment: It still get en.txt as lang when the file exists, and doesn't load any CSS or JS.

Comment: Try updated code. For CSS/JS/images use absolute path in your css, js, images files rather than a relative one. Which means you have to make sure path of these files start either with `http://` or a slash `/`.
   You can try adding this in your page's HTML header: `<base href="/" />` so that every relative URL is resolved from that URL and not the current URL.

Comment: First of all you're totally changing the problem stated in your question. You need to report if you're still getting `["lang"]=> string(19) "redirect:/index.php"` as asked in your question or not?

Comment: No, that's fixed. The problem now is different but similar. Thanks anyways, I give up.

Comment: That means your question is answered but you're adding a new problem right? Usually it is not recommended on SO as once a question is answered you mark it as accepted and post a new question with all the new problem statement.